# Count flags on user's content

Tags: theming, flags

In my Drupal 7 site I want to display how many times user's content was flagged. 
As option I want to set a global variable `counts` and display it in different parts of `*.tpl.php` files. The value can be calculated with `flag_get_counts($entity_type, $entity_id)` for each user's `node_id`. Function that calculates `counts` should be called in `template_page_preprocess()` to update value each time page is reloaded.

What is more efficient approach to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is using `template_preprocess_node()`.

Place the following code in `template.php` of your front end theme:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  // I suppose you don't want to do this for every content type on the site.
  switch ($vars['node']->type) {
    case 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE':
      $vars['count'] = flag_get_counts('node', $vars['node']->nid);
      break;
  }
}
```

This will make the `$count` variable available in `.tpl.php` files that are used for displaying nodes of your content type.